# Excel Worksheet's page setup not-working across workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to put different data into different worksheet in the same Workbook, and each worksheet have different page setup(like header,footer,etc).

When I execute the program, the data can be successfully displayed in different worksheet, but the page setup is not working (like header and footer is missing) when I checking print preview, does anyone know the reason?

bellow is the button click event:

```
private void btnExportAllToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = "StockReport(ALL)_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy HHmmss") + ".xls";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor; // change cursor to hourglass type
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.PrintCommunication = false;
            xlexcel.ScreenUpdating = false;
            xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = false; // Without this you will get two confirm overwrite prompts
            Workbook xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

            saveDataToSheet(xlWorkBook);
            xlexcel.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;

            //Save the excel file under the captured location from the SaveFileDialog
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = true;

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlexcel.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlexcel);

            // Clear Clipboard and DataGridView selection
            Clipboard.Clear();
            dgvStockReport.ClearSelection();

            // Open the newly saved excel file
            if (File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sfd.FileName);
        }
    }
```

bellow is the code for copy data from datagridview to sheet method, and I think the problem will be here but I cannot find it:

```
 //copy data from datagridview to clipboard and paste to excel sheet
    private void saveDataToSheet(Workbook xlWorkBook)
    {
        int sheetNo = 1;
        Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
        bool gotData = false;

        //load different data list to datagridview by changing the comboBox selected index
        for (int i = 0; i <= cmbType.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            cmbType.SelectedIndex = i;
            for (int j = 0; j <= cmbSubType.Items.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                cmbSubType.SelectedIndex = j;
                if (cmbType.Text.Equals(CMBPartHeader))
                {
                    gotData = loadPartStockData();//if data != empty return true, else false
                }
                else if (cmbType.Text.Equals(CMBMaterialHeader))
                {
                    gotData = loadMaterialStockData();//if data != empty return true, else false
                }

                if(gotData)//if datagridview have data
                {
                    copyAlltoClipboard();//select all from datagridview and copy to clipboard

                    //create new sheet
                    var xlSheets = xlWorkBook.Sheets as Sheets;
                    var xlNewSheet = (Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[sheetNo], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    xlWorkSheet = xlNewSheet;
                    xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(sheetNo);
                    xlWorkSheet.Name = cmbSubType.Text;

                    //Header and Footer setup
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&\"Calibri,Bold\"&11 " + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); ;
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&\"Calibri,Bold\"&16 (" + cmbSubType.Text + ") Stock List";
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&\"Calibri,Bold\"&11 PG -&P";
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Printed By " + dalUser.getUsername(MainDashboard.USER_ID);

                    //Page setup
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait;
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = true;
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 1;
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = 1;
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;
                    xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1";

                    // Paste clipboard results to worksheet range
                    xlWorkSheet.Select();
                    Range CR = (Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
                    CR.Select();
                    xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);

                    //content edit
                    Range tRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
                    tRange.Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                    tRange.Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
                    tRange.Font.Size = 11;
                    tRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                    tRange.Rows[1].interior.color = Color.FromArgb(237, 237, 237);//change first row back color to light grey

                    sheetNo++;

                    // Clear Clipboard and DataGridView selection
                    Clipboard.Clear();
                    dgvStockReport.ClearSelection();
                    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                }  
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm new here and coding as well, so if I'm doing anything wrong please let me know , thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 0):

After online research and modify my code about 4 hours, now it's work!

I try to save the workbook first,
then open it for insert data to worksheet and changing the page setup.

**CODE**:

```
private void btnExportAllToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

        sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.xls)|*.xls";
        sfd.FileName = "StockReport(ALL)_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss") + ".xls";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = Path.GetFullPath(sfd.FileName);
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor; // change cursor to hourglass type
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlexcel.PrintCommunication = false;
            xlexcel.ScreenUpdating = false;
            xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = false; // Without this you will get two confirm overwrite prompts
            Workbook xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

            //Save the excel file under the captured location from the SaveFileDialog
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sfd.FileName, 
                XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
                misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
                XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
                misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

            insertDataToSheet(path,sfd.FileName);

            xlexcel.DisplayAlerts = true;
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlexcel.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlexcel);

            // Clear Clipboard and DataGridView selection
            Clipboard.Clear();
            dgvStockReport.ClearSelection();
        }
    }
```

**here is the code for insert data to worksheet method:**

```
 private void insertDataToSheet(string path, string fileName)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;

        Workbook g_Workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(
            path,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


        bool gotData = false;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //load different data list to datagridview but changing the comboBox selected index
        for (int i = 0; i <= cmbType.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            cmbType.SelectedIndex = i;
            for (int j = 0; j <= cmbSubType.Items.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                cmbSubType.SelectedIndex = j;
                if (cmbType.Text.Equals(CMBPartHeader))
                {
                    gotData = loadPartStockData();//if data != empty return true, else false
                }
                else if (cmbType.Text.Equals(CMBMaterialHeader))
                {
                    gotData = loadMaterialStockData();//if data != empty return true, else false
                }

                if (gotData)//if datagridview have data
                {
                    Worksheet addedSheet = null;

                    int count = g_Workbook.Worksheets.Count;

                    addedSheet = g_Workbook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing,
                            g_Workbook.Worksheets[count], Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    addedSheet.Name = cmbSubType.Text;

                    addedSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&\"Calibri,Bold\"&11 " + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); ;
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&\"Calibri,Bold\"&16 (" + cmbSubType.Text + ") STOCK LIST";
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&\"Calibri,Bold\"&11 PG -&P";
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "Printed By " + dalUser.getUsername(MainDashboard.USER_ID);

                    //Page setup
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait;
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = false;
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = true;
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 1;
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin = 1;
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1;
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = false;
                    addedSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1";

                    copyAlltoClipboard();
                    addedSheet.Select();
                    Range CR = (Range)addedSheet.Cells[1, 1];
                    CR.Select();
                    addedSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);

                    Range tRange = addedSheet.UsedRange;
                    tRange.Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                    tRange.Borders.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
                    tRange.Font.Size = 11;
                    tRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                    tRange.Rows[1].interior.color = Color.FromArgb(237, 237, 237);//change first row back color to light grey

                    Clipboard.Clear();
                    dgvStockReport.ClearSelection();
                }
            }
        }
        g_Workbook.Worksheets.Item[1].Delete();
        g_Workbook.Save();
    }
```